# Electron login helper won't work - "Process is not in an inherited sandbox"

Tags: javascript, objective-c, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I'm trying to get my Electron Mac app to start at login, but I can't get it to work.

I'm implementing the start at login functionality from Electron's API (https://electronjs.org/docs/all#appsetloginitemsettingssettings-macos-windows) and that part seems to work. I've pushed the app to the Mac App Store and it's gone through. I've downloaded the app, set the app to login through the settings, but when I restart my Mac, the app won't open and I get this message in the console:

[image]

I'm building my MAS build using electron-builder, which leads me to believe it might have something to do with the build process.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what it might be about?

Comment: It'd be helpful, if you can provide more information, like code, so we can see what you did.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up signing my application again using Electron's guide - https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/mac-app-store-submission-guide.md - and now the start at login works.